# C++ boost sleep accuracy

Tags: c++, sleep, boost-thread

I'm experiencing strange issues with `boost::sleep()` function. I have this basic code:

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <boost/chrono.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

void thread_func()
{
    timeval start, end;
    gettimeofday( &start, NULL );
    boost::this_thread::sleep( boost::posix_time::milliseconds(1) ); // usleep(1000) here works just fine.
    gettimeofday( &end, NULL );

    int secs = end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec;
    int usec = end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec;
    std::cout << "Elapsed time: " << secs << " s and " << usec << " us" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    thread_func();

    boost::thread thread = boost::thread( thread_func );
    thread.join();

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that the `boost::sleep()` functions behaves differently in the created thread and in the main one. The output of this program is

```
Elapsed time: 0 s and 1066 us
Elapsed time: 0 s and 101083 us
```

i.e. the `boost::sleep()` function sleeps for 100 milliseconds in the created thread, whereas it works okay in the main thread (it sleeps for 1 ms). If I'm inside a created thread, I can't get the accuracy below 100 ms (for example by using `boost::posix_time::microseconds`). However, if I use `usleep(1000)`, it works just fine.

I'm using Fedora 18 (64-bit) 3.8.4 & Boost 1.50.0-5.fc18 on Intel i7 CPU. I also tested the code on different PC with Win 7 & Boost 1.48.0 and the problem does not occur, so I guess it should be related to the system configuration, but I have no clue how.

Comment: If you're not using a RTOS, you're not going to get very accurate results with sleep

Comment: @TonyTheLion 100 milliseconds is an anomaly on any OS.

Comment: can you try with std::this_thread::sleep from c++11 ?

Comment: @JohnKugelman it may be an anomaly, I still think relying on the accuracy of sleep is foolish

Comment: `boost::this_thread::sleep` is anyway [deprecated](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.this_thread.sleep), and so is `usleep`. Does it work with `boost::this_thread::sleep_for` and/or `nanosleep`?

Comment: @Useless Yes, it works with `boost::this_thread::sleep_for`. Will this function work the same on Windows? I need the code to be portable, that's the main reason I use boost in the first place (VS 2010 doesn't support C++11).

Comment: I can only suggest you try it and see, or ask on the Boost.Threads mailing list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`boost::this_thread::sleep` is deprecated ([see docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.this_thread.sleep)).

`usleep` is also deprecated (obsolete in POSIX.1-2001 and removed from POSIX.1-2008).

FWIW, in the older (1.44) boost headers I have installed locally, the relative delay version of `boost::this_thread_sleep` actually calls `gettimeofday` to calculate the *absolute* deadline, and then forwards to the absolute version (which is compiled out-of-line, so I don't have it handy). Note that `gettimeofday` was *also* marked obsolete in POSIX.1-2008.

The suggested replacements for all these are:

- `boost::this_thread::sleep_for` instead of `...::sleep` with a relative delay
- `boost::this_thread::sleep_until` instead of `...::sleep` with an absolute time
- `nanosleep` instead of `usleep`
- `clock_gettime` instead of `gettimeofday`

Comment: I marked this as an accepted answer because `sleep_for` seems to work on Windows as well and changing the code is only a matter of find & replace. However I still don't understand why `sleep` is behaving so strangely. The deprecation shouldn't change the behavior.

Comment: True, but without knowing which system call it uses internally I can only guess. You could try running with `strace` or `dtrace` if you want to find out what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware, that calling boost::this_thread::sleep() and related methods not only puts the thread to sleep but asks the scheduler to give the CPU to another thread that is ready for execution. So you are acutally measuring the maximum of the time of the sleep OR the time until the thread gets the CPU again.

Comment: I see in the boost docs that `boost::this_thread::sleep` and friends are cancellation points, but do you have a link to where it says they definitely yield as well?

Comment: @Useless I looked into the sources of 1.45.0 for the win32 code and there it is mapped to WaitForMultipleObjects which, according to MSDN doc, puts the thread into wait state, i.e. from the running into the waiting queue of the scheduler

Comment: Ah, ok. Might be worth editing your answer to be clear it's about Win - the question also mentions Fedora 18, and I'm not sure the same is true there.

Comment: For U**x systems (providing PThreads) it is either `timed_wait` or `nano_sleep` both of which are suspending the thread, making it to be put into the waiting queue (if I understood the manpages correctly).